# Java generic method to find 'max' object from collection using compareTo method problem

Tags: java, generics

Lets assume that we have

```
class A implements Comparable<A>
```

And

```
class B extends A
```

Now, I would like to have generic method that finds biggest object from collection, using `compareTo` method.

If I declare this method like so:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list)
```

It won't work for argument `List<B> list` because `B` does not parameterize `Comparable` with type `B`. For that method to work, it seems natural for me to change

```
Comparable<T>
```

To

```
Comparable<? super T>
```

So method after that change will look like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list)
```

Now passing argument `List<B> list` works fine and gives no errors. Fine. But when i change method signature to

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list)
```

It also works fine for argument `List<B> list`! And my question is WHY. Could someone explain that to me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<? extends T>` means "a List. We don't know a List of what, but whatever it is, we do know that it extends T or is T itself."

One effect of this is that when we take an element from the List, the compiler will know it as of type T. The actual runtime class of the item may be a subtype of T, as is always the case with polymorphism, but no one cares about that. We know it can be stored in a variable type T.

Another effect is that we can't put any element in the List, because we don't know of what the List is. So whatever we'd try to put inside, we don't know if it is of acceptable type, therefore we can't. But when finding the max it doesn't matter: we won't be adding anything anyway.

Therefore, a `List<B>` can also be taken as a `List<? extends A>` if needed (suddenly decide that we don't know don't care of what the List is, but whatever it is it extends A.) This is helping because then it allows to match the method signature, taking T as A.

Comment: But why `List<? extends T>` - which allows me to pass any collection of subtype `T` or  type `T` implicates that `List<B>` can be taken as `A` and `List<T>` don't? What does subtypes of `T` (when passing `List<B>` subtypes of `B`) have to do with that? Sorry if i'm not getting something obvious but it really bothers me.

Comment: @Mershel `List<B>` cannot be taken as A but can be taken as `List<? extends A>`, which enables to match `List<? extends T>` by taking T as A. `List<B>` cannot be taken as `List<A>` because they're too different. In a `List<A>` you can add an item which is of type A but not of type B. In a `List<B>` you can't. There is something a `List<A>` can do and a `List<B>` can't, therefore a `List<B>` cannot be taken as a `List<A>` (what if you were asked to do the thing that it cannot do?!!)

Comment: @kumesana explains what difference the wildcard makes, and let me add: we have two wildcards `extends` and `super` so that we can express flexibility in both directions, that is, respectively, _whatever I retrieve from the list at runtime, it's safe to treat it as a `T`_ (even if the list actually guarantees it contains only items some subtype of `T`) and _whatever list you've given me, it's safe to put a `T` into it_ (even if it's actually a list of some parent type of `T`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same thing.

**In the first example**, you're saying, "For some type `T`, such that I can cast any `T` to a `Comparable` of a supertype of `T`, then I'll accept a list of `T` and return an instance of `T`."

When you call the method with a `List<B>`, since every `B` is a `Comparable<A>`, it's therefore true to say: "I can cast any `B` to a `Comparable` of a supertype of `B`", and the type parameter `T` resolves to concrete type `B`.

**In the second example**, you're saying, "For some type `T`, such that I can cast any `T` to a Comparable of `T`, then I'll accept any list of `T` or any list of any subtype of `T`, and return an instance of `T`."

When you call *this* one with A `List<B>`, then the type parameter `T` resolves to `A`; of course any `A` is a `Comparable<A>`, and you can pass a `List<B>` into the method because a list of `B` is indeed a list of a subtype of `A`.

So that's why both will compile.

But you're asking about the purpose of being able to say `List<? extends T>`. This lets you remain open to receiving collections (or other parameterized types) of subclasses of the class you're working with. This is usually what you want when you're going to receive objects of a certain type and do something with them, and usually, you'd be equally happy to do that to a subtype (since a subtype should respect the same contract).

The `super` keyword means that you can work with objects whose type parameter is a superclass of your type parameter. The typical case is when you want to add an object to a collection. Suppose that `T` here resolves to concrete type `B`. If you received a `List<A> myList` then `List.add(B)` would be legal, because it's OK to add a `B` to a `List<A>`. It's also useful if your method returns, say, a `Set<T>` - in that case, the calling code can't assign it to a `Set<A>` even though everything in the set is an `A`, but if you instead return `Set<? super T>` then it can. In your case, you're going to call `Comparable<A>.compare(B)` and here, similarly, it's legal to pass an instance of `B` to `Comparable<A>.compare(A)`.

There's a mnemonic for this, PECS "Producer Extends, Consumer Super" discussed here: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: Ok, but in *second example* you wrote that Parameter `T` is resolved to `A` when passing `List<B>`.  Lets assume that is true. Then i don't understand why it can't be similarly resolved when method will accept `(List<T> list)` instead of 
`(List<? extends T> list)` I understand that `<? extends T>` allows me to work with any collection that will be a subtype of `T` (or type `T`), but what does it have to do with resolving parameter `T` as `A`?